# What methods are invoked in the Activity Lifecycle in the following cases:

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

Let's say I have a Hello World single Activity application.  I start this application.

What methods are invoked in each case:

- Home button is pressed: ?
  Back button is pressed: ?
  Phone call is received: ?

What methods are invoked once the user starts the application again via the app icon (assuming the OS hasn't had a "other apps need memory condition"):

- Home button was pressed: ?
  Back button was pressed: ?
  Phone call was received: ?

Thanks all.

Edit:  Extra Credit:  How can the user invoke `onPause` without invoking `onStop`?

Comment: onPause might be triggered, when a activity is on top which does not completely fill the screen to that the underlying activity is still partly visibile. Anyway: You could try to write a simple example and see and test the lifecycle on your own... you can use one of my questions and the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407192/problems-understanding-the-life-cycle-when-screen-goes-off-and-on

Comment: Go through this official document, and then you would understand the tricks. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

both pressing home button and receiving a call don't remove the activity from the task's stack, and will be available when you re-enter the app => onPause() => onStop().

as the [activity lifecycle diagram](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) shows, re-entering the app calls => onRestart() => onStart() => onResume()

pressing the back button instead kills the activity => onPause() => onStop() => onDestroy()

re-entering the app in this case calls the classics => onCreate() => onStart() => onResume()

**EDIT**

from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

> If an activity has lost focus but is
>   still visible (that is, a new
>   non-full-sized or transparent activity
>   has focus on top of your activity), it
>   is paused. A paused activity is
>   completely alive (it maintains all
>   state and member information and
>   remains attached to the window
>   manager), but can be killed by the
>   system in extreme low memory
>   situations.

Answer (score 7):

There can be several scenarios

1. **Opening the app from the app icon. following methods are called**

   onCreate()-->onStart()-->onResume()
2. **When user presses the home button**

   onPause()-->onStop()
3. **When user returns to the app from the Activity Stack**

   onRestart()-->onStart()--> onResume()
4. **When the app is running and user presses the power button**

   onPause()-->onStop()
5. **When user unlocks the phone**

   onRestart()-->onStart()--> onResume()
6. **When user gets an incoming call while you are in the app**

   onPause()
7. **When user returns to the app after disconnecting the phone call**

   onResume()
8. **When user presses the back button from the app**

   onPause()-->onStop()-->onDestroy()
9. **And when the user presses the home button and from the activity stack user swipes the app.onDestroy() method may or may not be called depending upon the OS contains the context of the Activity or not according to memory requirements**

Comment: please let me know if i missed any case

Comment: I think the phone call one may be OS dependent? If its a full screen phone call app, then your app will go through onPause>onStop. I think you are imagining more of an overlay phone call perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

Well see, while a sequence of events may occur with your hello world program, the same sequence may not occur in say a video game, because Android will probably Destroy it for taking up too much resources.

The best way I have found to see the lifecycle for my app is to override all the methods (onStart, onRestart,..., including the onSaveInstance and onRestoreInstance) and insert log statements in each one. Like so:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Call the super class 
    super.onDestroy();
    // Log the action
    Log.d("Debug", "onDestroy() has been called!");
}
```

Now I can go to logcat and see what events took place.