# Is there any particular behavior of Activity Lifecycle on Nexus 5?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Is there any particular behavior of Activity Lifecycle on Nexus 5?

### Problem

I have one Activity, and several Fragment are called like below:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = attachedActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_initial_setting, switchFragment);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

- every time Fragment is replaced
- and `addToBackStack(null)` is called
- each fragment behaves like pagination app

The problem is, for example you are in the 3rd fragment and click home button, and then re-open the app, the display forcibly go back to the first Activity, only on Nexus 5. And, I do not know how to debug or how to trace the behaviour.

Therefore,

- would you tell me if you know the possible reason behind the above problem
- or the general way how to debug if you encounter a weired behaviour of lifecycle along with home button

### Speculation

I've read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019686/what-methods-are-invoked-in-the-activity-lifecycle-in-the-following-cases) and noticed that when the home button is clicked, `onPause()` is called, and then I re-open the app `onRestart()` is called. But I do not know how to go to the next step.

Comment: check your developers settings maybe "Do not keep activities" is on?

Comment: @ViktorYakunin That's was the beginner's fault. You are right. Thanks!