# How to determine if a phone is in use or is in standby?

Tags: android

I am working on a research app that determines and graphs the phone use behavior of subjects in the study.
I want to know when the phone screen goes on, whether it is because user who turned it on or if it was because an external stimulus, e.g. a phone call or message came in.

I can't seem to find any information on this on the Android developer or Google.  Is this possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

For knowing when on/off screen is happened you can use next receiver for example:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        // do whatever you need to do here
        wasScreenOn = false;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // and do whatever you need to do here
        wasScreenOn = true;
    }
}
}
```

from here: https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

**(OR)** You can use PowerManager

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm. isInteractive();
```

From here: [how to check screen on/off status in onStop()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350258/how-to-check-screen-on-off-status-in-onstop)

And here: [How can I tell if the screen is on in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474367/how-can-i-tell-if-the-screen-is-on-in-android)

Last two possibly duplicate

But in any case you need some background worker, that would be take information about on/off screen and events that turning on/off your screen. For that you can use another receiver that would receive events when phone was called or something else, and store info like: "event-time", "event-time"... in some storage like a list.
In this case you can take info about what called on/off your screen.