# Detect If User Stopped Using His Phone - Android - .Net MAUI

Tags: android, xamarin.android, maui

I'm working on Android application to to display images after x minutes without user interaction.

The user will be using an Android device with a Whiteboard application. And when the user stops using the device I should launch my application to display images.

I need help and guidance on how to detect if the user touchs the screen even if my application is not active.

Thanks,

Comment: You can try to refer to this case: [Detect Always-On Display when trying to determine if the screen is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216558/detect-always-on-display-when-trying-to-determine-if-the-screen-is-off).

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it that way.  There is no way to get a notification when the user touches the screen if your app isn't in the foreground.  Well, you might be able to do it using the Accessibility service, but then it won't be allowed on the Play Store (they don't allow accessibility be used for non-accesibility purposes).

You can do this within just your app.  Or you can try registering for the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF broadcast with a broadcast receiver, which is sent when Google thinks the device is no longer interactive (but it will be Google's definition of that, which isn't well defined).  However if your app is killed in the background for resources it may not come through.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually my application is in the foreground. I added a service to launch the application after 5 minutes when it's OnSleep as a temporary solution.
For the Play Store, I don't think it will be a problem as the application will be used only by the internal team.
I will take a look for Accessibility service and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF broadcast.
Anyone have some articles or code samples for Accessibility service and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF broadcast can be helpful.
Thanks