# Android Java Service to detect screen state

Tags: java, android

I am PHP, in oher words newby in JAVA.
I wrote service which every second checks if the screen is on or off, but need help, cuz at last step my Log.d shows "on off on off.." instead of showing "on on on..." when screen is on (and "off off off..." when screen is OFF.

Simple main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "TAGG";
    private Button startServiceButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startServiceButton = findViewById(R.id.startService);
        startServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startService(new Intent(getApplication(), MyService.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

..and receiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private boolean screenOff;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

.. and here is the problem:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private  static final String TAG = "TAGG";
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public int xMin = 1*60*24*30;//work a month

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        CountDownTimer countDownTimer =  new CountDownTimer(
                60000*xMin,1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onTick: "+millisUntilFinished/1000 );

                boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);

                if (!screenOn) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTick: OFF");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTick: ON");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFinish: " );
            }
        }.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // REGISTER RECEIVER THAT HANDLES SCREEN ON AND SCREEN OFF LOGIC
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

First main ask:
Please tell me how to correctly output state of screen each second.

Second ask:
ps General idea - is to create a service which starts after button press and then checks/modifies every second system parameter only when the screen is on (the app can be minimised). When screen is off it would be good to pause service, but did not found out how. How to check system parameter I know. Maybe there is simple way to do this then my way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check screen on/off status in onStop()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350258/how-to-check-screen-on-off-status-in-onstop)

Comment: @C.F.G - seems it is working. Thanks! Will accept if you will post answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Activity:**

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

boolean isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
```

**In Fragment:**

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) requireContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
```

[image]